# Jest 18.0.0 setTimeout is not working

Tags: ecmascript-6, jestjs

I tried to make a promise like this

```
console.info('Promise Start', new Date())
Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.info('Promise End', new Date())
    console.info('State:', store.getState().user)
    return resolve(wizard.props().location)
  }, API_TIMEOUT )
})
```

But the delay between `Promise Start` and `Promise End` is less than API_TIMEOUT, even 10 ms.
I see that Jest is mocking the `setTimeout` function but how do I use the original `setTimeout` function?
I tried to use `jest.useRealTimers()` but no effects!

Comment: Can you post the entire test you wrote ? Where did you try to use `jest.useRealTimers()` ?